# Trigger for a ContextMenu Visibility?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, contextmenu

I have a Listbox that starts off with no items inside. When a user uses the GUI to select a value from a combobox and clicks the add Button, the the listbox gets an item added.  The Listbox also has a contextmenu set.

How can i use XAML to make sure that the Listbox.contextmenu.Visibility property set to hidden when there are no items in the listbox??

**UPDATE**

I actually used this code in the end.  Please comment on its appropriatness

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
                <MenuItem Header="Buy"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Sell"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger  Property="ListBox.HasItems" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not think that messing with the visibility of the ContextMenu is a good idea, just `null` out the whole menu if the list is empty.

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <!-- Menu here -->
        </ContextMenu>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You could also choose to only define ContextMenus on the items themselves using the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle.aspx), then no ContextMenu can be opened without items but that might of course not fit your scenario.

Comment: Thanks i actually used this in the end.

Comment: <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
                    <MenuItem Header="Buy"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sell"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger  Property="ListBox.HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

Comment: Why not null it out? Changing the visibility seems like abuse of the property to me. (Also, if my answer solved your problem or sufficiently helped you can accept it via the checkmark outline on the left)